# Getting an error when trying to trigger a function for state change

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to code a react component for a modal and getting the error: "Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function" when the openModal() is called. Below is my code:

```
class Header {

  constructor() {
      this.state = { showModal: false };
  } 

  openModal() {
      this.setState({showModal: true});
  }

  closeModal() {
      this.setState({showModal: false});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Header">
        <ModalDialog heading="heading" show={this.state.showModal}>
          <p>Body</p>
        </ModalDialog>
        <div className="Header-container">
          <Navigation className="Header-nav" />
          <div className="Navigation2">

            <Button bsStyle='primary' onClick={this.openModal.bind(this)}>Sign in</Button>

            <Button bsStyle='info' href="/register" onClick={Link.handleClick}>Sign up</Button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

class ModalDialog {

  render() {
    if (this.props.show) {
        return (
        <div className="Overlay">
          <Modal heading={this.props.heading}>
            <div>{this.props.children}</div>
          </Modal>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
};

class Modal {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Modal effect">
        <h3>{this.props.heading}</h3>
        <div className="content">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

I am also trying to pass in a className into the element `<div className="Modal effect">` from the Header component to change the dimensions of the Modal, is this possible?

Would be great if somebody could help me out with this. I am just starting out with React. Thanks

Comment: I managed to fix it, had to add super() above the code. But regarding passing classes into the component. is there a solution for this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I am also trying to pass in a className into the element  from the Header component to change the dimensions of the Modal, is this possible?*

This is typically what props are made for, passing static information such size.
So simply pass your class/size/staticprops as a prop like this:

```
<ModalDialog size={//whatever you need} className="Modal effect"/>
```

From ModalDialog pass it to Modal

```
<Modal size={this.props.size} />
```

And then you just have to use it inside your Modal for whatever purpose you want. More about props in general :https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with reactJS but this looks wrong to me:

```
constructor() {
      this.state = { showModal: false };
}
```

Should it be:

```
constructor() {
      this.setState = ({ showModal: false });
}
```

?

Otherwise your Header class sets its state attribute to `{ showModal: false }`

Which obviously has no 'setState' member function.